# C++ linker error for extern-declared global object

Tags: c++, variables, namespaces, definition, extern

I have trouble using an `extern`-declared global object. As I understand it I should be able to declare an object as `extern` in a header file, define it in a source file, then use the object in any other source file where the header is included. However, with the following structure, I get a linker error saying that the `logger` symbol is undefined.

logger.hpp:

```
#ifndef MY_LOGGER_H
#define MY_LOGGER_H

namespace foo {
class Logger {
public:
    void log(int num);
};

extern Logger logger;
} // foo

#endif
```

logger.cpp:

```
#include "logger.hpp"
using namespace foo;

void Logger::log(int num) { /* Do stuff */ }

Logger logger;
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "logger.hpp"
using namespace foo;

int main() {
    logger.log(3); // arbitrary number
}
```

If I declare a `Logger` in `main()`, everything works fine, so the header and source files are being included and linked correctly.
I get the same error using built-in types (e.g. `int`), so I don't think it's an issue with the `Logger` class itself either.

Appologies if this is a dumb question, I have a few years' experience in C++ but I've avoided global variables like the plague until now.

Comment: Are you compiling `logger.cpp` and `main.cpp` together? `g++ main.cpp logger.cpp -o program` or separately and linking the object files afterwards?

Comment: Btw, you should have `namespace foo { ... Logger logger; }`

Comment: The two are being compiled separately. `logger.cpp` is compiled into an archive file (`source.a`) first, then `main.cpp` is compiled and linked with `source.a` later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declaration

```
Logger logger;
```

defines a variable in the global namespace.

You need to write using qualified name

```
#include "logger.hpp"

using namespace foo;

void Logger::log(int num) { /* Do stuff */ }

Logger foo::logger;
```

From the C++ 20 Standard (9.8.1.2 Namespace member definitions)

> 2 Members of a named namespace can also be defined outside that
> namespace by explicit qualification (6.5.3.2) of the name being
> defined, provided that the entity being defined was already declared
> in the namespace and the definition appears after the point of
> declaration in a namespace that encloses the declaration’s namespace

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {
    class Logger {
    public:
        void log(int num);
    };

    extern Logger logger;
} // foo

using namespace foo;

void Logger::log(int num) { /* Do stuff */ }

Logger foo::logger;

int main() 
{
    logger.log(3);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the definitions in `logger.cpp` in the `foo` namespace:

```
#include "logger.hpp"

namespace foo { // not "using namespace foo"

void Logger::log(int num) { /* Do stuff */ }

Logger logger;  // this is now the "foo::Logger" you declared in logger.hpp
} // namespace foo
```